# RichTextBox for source code

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I have some application that parses source code of a programming language. I'm using `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` as a code editor. I highlight language's keywords with the following alogrithm:

> - Whenever text is changed, back to the beginning of the last word, call this substring word.
> - If the keywords contains word then set color of word to blue
>     Otherwise set color of word to black

I am using `RichTextBox.SelectionStarts`, `RichTextBox.Select(int, int)` and `RichTextBox.SelectionColor`. That is working just fine.

However, when I press Enter key, the cursor backs to most begin of the line. As a source-code editor, I want it to follow the last line begging. I put the padding white space characters from the previous line in a string `str`, and then `richTextBox.Text = richTextBox.Text.Insert(richTextBox.SelectionStarts, str)`. When I do so, all text highlighting is corrupted, that all text is in blue color.

Can anyone give a suggestion how to append line padding spaces without corrupting the highlighting?

Comment: Assign the SelectionText property to insert text without destroying the formatting of existing text.  Opposite of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271550/removing-richtextbox-lines-while-keeping-the-colour-of-remaining-lines-in-c-shar/7273057#7273057

Comment: @HansPassant Can you put your comment as an answer? I would accept it. Or prefer to close question as an exact duplicate ? :P :P

Comment: @HansPassant Besides, it is `SelectedText`, not `SelectionText` :P :P

Answer (score 2):

No clue what is the exact problem of your code. Maybe you should look at the established solutions. E.g., [Scintilla.NET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) is a .NET wrapper for the well-known [Scintilla](http://www.scintilla.org/) control. It is extensible with custom lexers so it might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see. Here is a good start:

Put this at the very top of your form:

`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

Then put this into the `RichTextBox` `TextChanged`:

```
            // getting keywords/functions
            string keywords = @"\b(abstract|as|base|break|case|catch|checked|continue|default|delegate|do|else|event|explicit|extern|false|finally|fixed|for|foreach|goto|if|implicit|in|interface|internal|is|lock|namespace|new|null|object|operator|out|override|params|private|protected|public|readonly|ref|return|sealed|sizeof|stackalloc|switch|this|throw|true|try|typeof|unchecked|unsafe|using|virtual|volatile|while)\b";
            MatchCollection keywordMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, keywords);

            // getting types/classes from the text 
            string types = @"\b(Console)\b";
            MatchCollection typeMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, types);

            // getting comments (inline or multiline)
            string comments = @"(\/\/.+?$|\/\*.+?\*\/)";
            MatchCollection commentMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, comments, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            // getting strings
            string strings = "\".+?\"";
            MatchCollection stringMatches = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, strings);

            string stringz = "bool|byte|char|class|const|decimal|double|enum|float|int|long|sbyte|short|static|string|struct|uint|ulong|ushort|void";
            MatchCollection stringzMatchez = Regex.Matches(codeRichTextBox.Text, stringz);

            // saving the original caret position + forecolor
            int originalIndex = codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart;
            int originalLength = codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength;
            Color originalColor = Color.Black;

            // MANDATORY - focuses a label before highlighting (avoids blinking)
            label1.Focus();

            // removes any previous highlighting (so modified words won't remain highlighted)
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = 0;
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = codeRichTextBox.Text.Length;
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = originalColor;

            // scanning...
            foreach (Match m in keywordMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            }

            foreach (Match m in typeMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.DarkCyan;
            }

            foreach (Match m in commentMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
            }

            foreach (Match m in stringMatches)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Brown;
            }

            foreach (Match m in stringzMatchez)
            {
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = m.Index;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = m.Length;
                codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Purple;
            }

            // restoring the original colors, for further writing
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionStart = originalIndex;
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionLength = originalLength;
            codeRichTextBox.SelectionColor = originalColor;

            // giving back the focus
            codeRichTextBox.Focus();
```

That will provide `RichTextBox` coding syntax for C#

If you want coding syntax for another language, replace the contents of the `keywords` `string`, and the contents of the `stringz` `string`, with the language of your choice.

To change the `Color` of the `keywords`, or `stringz`, then look at the `foreach (Match m in keywordMatches)`, or `foreach (Match m in stringzMatchez)`

If you are doing any other language than C#, then remove `types`, and edit the `strings` and `comments`

I hope this helps you :)