# RichTextBox styling removed on save

Tags: vb.net

When I use:

```
Me.RichTextBox.SelectionFont = New Font(Me.RichTextBox.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Italic)
```

The selected text becomes italic, but when I use

```
lines(i - 5) = Me.Auto_Time.Text

Me.RichTextBox.Lines = lines
```

it saves the text from `Me.Auto_Time` but I lost all italic from richtextbox?

Comment: possible duplicate of [removing RichTextBox lines while keeping the colour of remaining lines in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271550/removing-richtextbox-lines-while-keeping-the-colour-of-remaining-lines-in-c-shar)

Comment: The property `.Text` from a TextBox only contains Text, not format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the .text and then pass .rtf for formatting:

```
Me.RichTextBox.Lines = Lines
Me.RichTextBox.Rtf = Me.Auto_Time.Rtf
```

Comment: Yes but Me.Auto_Time.Text is text box when I used Me.RichTextBox.Lines = Lines I just lost all Italic form richtext

Comment: I must have misread your question. You have a normal multiline textbox with unformatted text, and you are attempting to move this text to your RichTextBox while maintaining the formatting scheme you had in your RichTextBox?