# How to disable autoscrolling in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, richtextbox, autoscroll

How can I disable autoscrolling in `richTextBox` by simultaneously enabled possibility of text selection?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the focus to another control is the simple way.

In general, you don't want the user to see these updates at all.  It tends to cause a lot of flicker while you are updating the content.  The boilerplate solution that most controls provide for that is their BeginUpdate and EndUpdate methods.  RichTextBox is missing them however.  You can add them though with a wee bit of pinvoke.  You'll find the required code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3282911/17034).

Answer (score 0):

Please ,
Make ReadOnly is true for selection text but disable for change String.
Ex. : 
RichTextBox1.ReadOnly=True
RichTextBox1.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.None;