# RichTextBox.Rtf property not setting to passed value

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf

I have read a number of articles about formatting text in a `RichTextBox` as the user types by selecting text based on a search and then setting the `SelectionColour` property; I don't like this as the flashy behaviour of the selection doesn't look very good.

With that in mind, I am instead using a procedure to 'build' the raw RTF text which defines the formatting required based on the text and then just sets the `Rtf` property of the `RichTextBox`.

However, what I can't understand is that, after I've created the raw RTF string, when this is passed to the `Rtf` property of the `RichTextBox`, it's getting overridden by something completely different.

This is the raw RTF string which I've created with the procedure:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;
\red65\green105\blue225;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green192\blue203;
\red128\green128\blue128;\red255\green165\blue0;\red34\green139\blue34;}
{\fonttbl\n{\f0\fswiss\fcharset1252 Courier New;}\n}{\cf2select \cf5left}}
```

When I set the `Rtf` property of the `RichTextBox` to this string, what it actually sets it to is:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl
{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Courier New;}}\r\n{\colortbl;\red65\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue0;}
\r\n\viewkind4\uc1\pard\cf1\f0\fs24 se\\cf5\cf2 cf1lect left\par\r\n}\r\n
```

What is even more confusing to me is that if I set the `Rtf` property of the `RichTextBox` in the form constructor rather than in this procedure, it does set it to the passed value exactly and I get the text formatting that I want.

What I am trying to understand is why the `Rtf` property is not being set to what I pass it and seems to be getting set to something completely different.

Comment: Instead of trying to change rtf, use [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3282911/3110834) to disable flicker when updating `SelectionBackColor`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer; this seems to be working quite well initially; I have not stress tested it yet but it looks very promising. If you'd like to post an answer for this I'd be happy to up-vote it; although I think I may want to keep it open as I would still like to really understand (albeit more for academic purposes at this point) why the Rtf property behaves in this way :-)

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the offer. Since the linked post is a complete answer, I'm not goring to post an answer based on that. Instead, when you find an answer useful, you can vote for it :)